# Test data generation tools supported by specflow

Tags: tdd, bdd, specflow, test-data, data-generation

Is there any tool compatible with Specflow to generate test data. As in specflow while writing test scenarios you have to specify sample data as hard coded. Is there any tool which can generate test data for specflow test scenarios.
Thanks

Comment: Does my answer is satisfactory? Do you need any additional help?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to generate Test Data as Examples in Scenario Outline to treat each example as a separate unit test, it is not possible. But that's the point of BDD, you expect from each scenario to be well-described, and clear on what is happening there.

```
Given I have created user named <name>
When I try to login
Then user should access home page

Examples:
|name |
|Bob  |
|Jack |
```

Depending on your case you can write steps to generate test data (in Backgroud on in the scenario itself) with any tool of your choice, and in another step check your requirements.

```
Given I have created 100 random users
When I try to login with each user
Then all users should access home page
```